# How to update state onChange if it's an array of objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have some state:

```
  const [budget, setBudget] =
    React.useState<{ name: string; budget: number | null }[]>();
```

And I'm trying to use a TextField to update that state based on the name and value of the input field:

```
    budget.map((item) => {
      content.push(
        <TextField
          name={item.name}
          id={item.name}
          label={item.name}
          type="tel"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      );
    });
```

It's a weird situation to be in I know, but the input fields aren't pre-determined values so I have to dynamically render them which makes life hard.

I've tried the following onChange function but it's not working:

```
  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => () => {
    const newOne = budget?.map((item) =>
      Object.entries(item).map(([key, value]) => {
        if (key === event.target.name) {
          return [key, event.target.value];
        }
        return [key, value];
      })
    );
    setBudget(newOne);
  };
```

I'm creating lots of arrays unintentionally and getting the following error (not sure how to return just the key and value):

```
Argument of type '(string | number | null)[][][] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ name: string; budget: number | null; }[] | undefined>'.
```

Comment: Could you please reproduce the problem on codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you overthinked your handle function, or I didn't understood your need :

```
export function Test () {
    const [budget, setBudget] = React.useState<{ name: string; budget: number | null }[]>();

    const handleChange = React.useCallback((event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setBudget(
        actualBudget => actualBudget?.map(
            item => item.name === event.target.name ? { ...item, value: event.target.value } : item,
        ),
    ), [setBudget]);

    return budget?.map(item => (
        <input
            name={item.name}
            id={item.name}
            placeholder={item.name}
            type="tel"
            value={item.budget}
            onChange={handleChange}
        />
    ));
}
```